# $\varepsilon$-approximation by a continuous function using oscillation

Tags: general-topology, approximation

It is an easy to prove fact that for any function $f$ on an interval $I\subset\mathbb R$, if the oscillation of $f$ at every $x\in I$ is $<\varepsilon$, then there exists a continuous function $g$ on $I$ such that $|f(x)-g(x)|<3\varepsilon$, say, for all $x\in I$.

I'm looking for some generalization of the above in topological setting. Namely, I would like to learn in which topological spaces $X$ the following holds.

There is a quantity $\eta(\varepsilon)>0$, such that $\eta(\varepsilon)\to0$ when $\varepsilon\to0$, with the property that: for every open subset $O\subset X$, $\varepsilon>0$, and every function $f\colon O\to\mathbb R$ such that $\omega_f(x)<\varepsilon$ at all $x\in O$, there is a continuous function $g$ on $O$ such that $|f(x)-g(x)|<\eta(\varepsilon)$ for all $x\in O$.

(I feel the problem might be pretty technical, with, e.g., normality of $X$ and Tietze being used to solve it.)

Comment: What is $\omega_f$ in this generalized setting?

Comment: I suppose you can define $\omega_f(x) = \inf\{\omega_f(U) : U \ \text{is an open set containing} \ x\}$ where $\omega_f(U) = \sup_{x \in U} \ f(x) - \inf_{x \in U} \ f(x)$

Comment: I meant rather $\omega_f(x)=\inf_U\sup_{y\in U}{|f(x)-f(y)|}$ but both definitions of $\omega_f(x)$ work in the same way (the difference is up to multiplier 2).

Comment: I guess in the third paragraph there should be $x\in O$ instead of $x\in I$. Also, since you consider functions only from $O$, but not from $X$, it suffices to consider a case when $O=X$.

Comment: Sure, I've corrected this $I$ to $O$. Thanks!

Comment: So, it's the Katetov--Tong theorem that made the job here (shame to say, I've just only learnt about it). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define functions $f_+$ and $f_-$ from $O\to \Bbb R$ as follows. For each $x\in O$ put $f_+(x)=\sup_{U} \inf_{y\in U} f(y)$ and $f_-(x)= \inf_{U} \sup_{y\in U} f(y)$, where $U$ ranges over all open neighborhoods of $x$. It is easy to check that the function $f_+$ is lower semicontinuous, the function $f_-$ is upper semicontinuous (see definitions below), and for each $x\in O,$
$ f(x)-\varepsilon< f_+(x)\le f(x)\le f_-(x)< f(x)+ \varepsilon.$ 
Thus  $ f_-(x)- \varepsilon<f(x)< f_+(x)+\varepsilon$.  Exercise 1.7.15.b from Ryszard Engelking’s “General Topology” (2nd ed., Heldermann, Berlin, 1989) claims that if the space $O$ is a normal then there exists a continuous function $h$ from $O$ to $\Bbb R$ such that  $ f_-(x)- \varepsilon\le h(x)\le  f_+(x)+\varepsilon$ for each $x\in O$. Then $f(x)-\varepsilon\le h(x)\le f(x)+\varepsilon$, so $|f(x)-h(x)|\le\varepsilon$ for each $x\in O$.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you able to find a counterexample in a space that is not $T_4$?

Comment: @MtHood I looked a bit for it on Tychonoff spaces, which are not normal, but it looks not so easy to construct.

Comment: @ Alex Ravsky My feeling is the same, but I'm far from being well-educated in general topology, so all examples of not normal spaces I'm able to work with are already non-Hausdorff. And here, if the topology is not too rich (like e.g. for $\mathbb R$ with co-countable topology) small oscillation everywhere makes the function close to a constant.

Comment: @ Alex Ravsky If we work with the domain $O$ being an open subset of $X$, and not $X$ itself, shouldn't we assume rather $T_5$ instead of just $T_4$, since even an open subset of a $T_4$ space need not be $T_4$ in general (like, e.g., for the Tychonoff plank). Does the use of $O$ instead of $X$ interfere with the Katetov-Tong proof in your opinion?

Comment: @MtHood As I noted in the comment, since we consider functions only from $O$, but not from the whole $X$, we don’t care about $X$, only about $O$.

Comment: @MtHood I considered classic examples of non-normal Tychonoff spaces, namely, the square $S\times S$ of the Sorgenrey arrow (see “General Topology”, Example 1.2.2), where $S$ is the real line endowed with the topology generated by the base consisting of half-intervals $[a,b)$, $a<b$ or Niemytski plane (see Example 1.2.4). Similarly to Example 1.5.10 we can show that these spaces are non-normal, because  each of them is separable and   
Contains a closed discrete subset $M$ of cardinality continuum.  For instance, $M=\{(x,-x)\in S\times S: x\in\Bbb R\}$.

Comment: But I think that for the beginning any counterexamples are interesting.